# XPath for element with maximum value?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a XML file containing different publications. I want to find the publication with the highest amount of `timesCited` which is published before 2010. I have this as of now:

```
/publications/publication[timesCited = max(/publications/publication/timesCited)]
                         [yearFinished < 2010]
```

The problem is that this checks for the highest `timesCited`, which is a publication from 2011, and thus returns nothing. I want to find the publication with the highest amount of citations before 2010. How would I go about this?

Comment: Share your XML source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expression should works

```
/publications/publication[yearFinished < 2010][timesCited = max(/publications/publication[yearFinished < 2010]/timesCited)]
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//publication[yearFinished < 2010]
             [timesCited = max(//publication[yearFinished < 2010]/timesCited)]
```

will select the pre-2010 `publication` element with the maximum `timesCited`, as requested.